# SQL conditions - select ID who have multiple values in a column

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

Having this COLORS table:

[image]

How do I select the ID who have both COLOR RED & PINK? (Could be more than 2 colors)

```
 SELECT ID
 FROM COLORS
 WHERE COLOR IN ('RED')
 AND ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method is aggregation and `having`:

```
select id
from colors c
where color in ('RED', 'PINK')
group by id
having count(*) = 2;
```

This assumes that your original data has no duplicates.  If that is the case, use `count(distinct color) = 2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HAVING` clause like

```
SELECT ID FROM COLORS GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

You can read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID
 FROM COLORS
 WHERE COLOR LIKE 'RED'
 OR COLOR LIKE 'PINK'
```

If you want more colors:

```
SELECT ID
 FROM COLORS
 WHERE COLOR LIKE 'RED'
 OR COLOR LIKE 'PINK'
 OR COLOR LIKE 'BLACK'
```